# BIRT Table - How to stop the data being truncate on report

Tags: java, birt

Using Birt 4.2

Is there a way to stop the data cell truncating the data viewed in the table.

Currently there's a method to stop wrapping (No Wrapping on the general tab of table cells) but this only stop it from appearing on two lines.

To recreate you do the following

1. You create a dataset
2. Bind the data set to a table on the report
3. Drop the data cells in to the table
4. Set all data, cell and rows to No Wrapping
5. Export to XLS

The columns are not auto adjusting to the size of the data, so data viewed in the cells is being truncated when exporting to XLS.

Does anyone know how to tell BIRT to adjust the column size and not truncate the data being viewed in a table in BIRT

Comment: Is the data actually being truncated, or is it simply not visible?  When you open the report as HTML is there a difference in actual data (given that some may be in Excel, but not visible).

Comment: the data is not visable, as the coloumn size in excel isn't set to display the whole cell. in HTML it works fine, as the cell adjust for the largest data value. Excel output seems to set the size of the data, which means the data is not visable.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I can tell you where to start looking.  Export to excel is governed by something called the "Excel Emitter'.  The one that comes with standard BIRT is not very robust.  There are a number of add-on Emitters available, that can do lots of magic things.  Googling 'BIRT excel emitter' returns around 13k hits.  I am not aware of a listing that offers, details of what all the different emitters offer.

Comment: i am using both the standard one and Tribix excel emitter. Both come out the same, i also got it wrong, the HTML version also has a size set for cells, thus the cells are being truncated.

Comment: Ben is the issue solved i have same problem i tried doing "No WARP" for white space attribute,setting Auto Layout but nothing works :( :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest versions of the SpudSoft Excel Emitter have optional support for considering the size of header/footer content when auto-calculating column widths.
Use the RenderOption: ExcelEmitter.AutoColWidthsIncludeTableHeader (Boolean, set to True).

Answer (score 0):

Not a total complete answer, but [Spudsoft Birt Excel Emitter](http://www.spudsoft.co.uk/2011/10/the-spudsoft-birt-excel-emitters/) has the ability to auto adjust the width of cells based on its data. but it only compares a certain amount of rows. It will not handle Headers.